# Jwt-token disappear when i refresh my page

Tags: vue.js, cookies, jwt, nuxt.js, strapi

i had just finished my authentication on nuxt with the NuxtStrapi plugin and when i tried to register, it worked all fine but when i tried to go on another page or to refresh, my cookie was disappearing. I have been told to use the useCookie to control the expire date of my cookie composable but i think i configured it terribly and it didn't worked at all.

Here is the script of my register form :

```
<script setup>
import { createAvatar } from '@dicebear/core';
import { lorelei } from '@dicebear/collection';

const username = ref('');
const email = ref('');
const password = ref('');
const avatarUrl = ref('');
const formSubmitted = ref(false);

const { register } = useStrapiAuth();
const token = useStrapiToken()

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    await register({
      username: username.value,
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value,
    });
    const cookie = useCookie('strapi_jwt', {
    maxAge: 600 * 60, // here you define in seconds or ms how long it should last aka when it will expire
    expire: new Date(Date.now() + (600 * 60 * 1000)) // set the expiration time 600 minutes (10 hours) from now
  });
  cookie.value = token;
    const avatar = createAvatar(lorelei, {
          size: 128,
        }).toDataUriSync();       
        avatarUrl.value = avatar;
        formSubmitted.value = true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
</script>
```

and here is my config:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config

export default {
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/strapi'],
    strapi: {
      url: process.env.STRAPI_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
      prefix: '/api',
      version: 'v4',
      cookie: {},
      cookieName: 'strapi_jwt',
    },
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone !

Answer (score 0):

From the [nuxt documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie):

> expires: Specifies the Date object to be the value for the Expires Set-Cookie attribute. By default, no expiration is set. **Most clients will consider this a "non-persistent cookie" and will delete it on a condition like exiting a web browser application.**

> Note: The cookie storage model specification states that if both expires and maxAge is set, then maxAge takes precedence, but not all clients may obey this, so if both are set, they should point to the same date and time!

So maybe I will try to set only `maxAge`.